# jquery change global variable inside function

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var variable = "before";

change();

alert(variable);

function change(){

variable = "after";

}
```

Does in possible to change global variable inside function without return ? I need after call function `change` have output "after"

Comment: It is possible, but why would you use globals to begin with? Why can't the function take one argument?

Comment: I want set variable globally from ajax response

Comment: You may want to check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call), because that's seems like a pretty common mistake.

Comment: Yes you need not return the variable. The callback would change its value.

Comment: Short answer is yes. Long answer is you should read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Variable_scope), and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/500459/2782135), to get to know all you need about scopes in JavaScript.

Comment: If it's ajax, you should say so in the question, as Asynchronous Javascript And XML is ... wait for it... asynchronous, and setting global variables is not the solution, as others above have noted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, but remember to NOT put the `var` keyword in front of it inside the function.

### ERORR - DOES NOT WORK:

```js
var variable = "before";

change();

alert(variable);

function change() {

  var variable = "after";

}
```

### WORKS:

```js
var variable = "before";

change();

alert(variable);

function change() {

  variable = "after";

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should avoid declaring global variables since they add themselves as properties to the `window`.  However, to answer your question, yes you can change global variables by setting either changing `variable` or `window.variable`.

Example:
http://jsbin.com/xujenimiwe/3/edit?js,console,output

```
var variable = "before"; // will add property to window --  window.variable

console.log(variable);

change();

console.log(window.variable);

function change(){

 variable = "after"; // can also use window.variable = "after"
}
```

Please let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: Can you please explain why this does not work? https://jsfiddle.net/y6etz8w3/1/ I already tried setting window.selectedElement as well